# Passport stamp - France Study Visa and Stopover in Spain

Tags: schengen, france, spain, switzerland, long-stay-visas

It's my first time traveling to Europe, so I don't know very well all the process with immigration.
I have a Type D Visa (Study) for France, and I'm planning to go to Geneva as my final destination (near the city in France I'm going to), with a stopover in Madrid.

So the question is the following: Where do I have to get the passport stamped? Madrid or Geneva? And will I have any problems with the fact that the stamp will be a Spanish or Swiss one? Will French immigration give me headaches with that? Does it have to be a French stamp?

Answer (score 3):

> Where do I have to get the passport stamped? Madrid or Geneva?

Your passport will be stamped in Madrid.

> And will I have any problems with the fact that the stamp will be a Spanish or Swiss one?

No.

> Will French immigration give me headaches with that?

No.

> Does it have to be a French stamp?

No.